# AX Dynamics Table Dependencies using SQL

Tags: sql, dependencies, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm trying to determine the dependency hierarchy for any given table within AX Dynamics 2012 R3 within **SQL**. I understand that the table and relationships information is contained within the **MODELELEMENT** table within the model database.

I'm struggling to navigate this hierarchy to determine the dependent tables.

**Example ..**

```
select  [parent].[Name]                 , 
        [type].[ElementTypeName]        ,
        [relationship].[Name]           ,
        [relationship].[ParentHandle]   ,
        [relationship].[RootHandle]     ,
        [dependents].[Name]

from [dbo].[MODELELEMENT] as [parent] 

    inner join [dbo].[MODELELEMENT] as [relationship]
    on  [relationship].[ParentHandle] = [parent].[ElementHandle]
    and [relationship].[ElementType] = 25

        inner join [dbo].[ElementTypes] as [type]
        on [relationship].[ElementType] = [type].[ElementType]

        left join [dbo].[MODELELEMENT] as [dependents]
        on [dependents].[ParentHandle]  = [relationship].[ElementHandle]
        or [dependents].[RootHandle]    = [relationship].[ElementHandle]

where   [parent].[ElementType] = 44 
and     [parent].[Name] = 'PriceDiscTable'
```

The results of this query are shown below ...

[image]

The above example details the 'TableRelations' which have been created for the PriceDiscTable however nothing in the **MODELELEMENT** table references the *relationship element* and the *relationship element* references the parent table in both the **Roothandle** and the **ParentHandle**?

Can anyone explain how I'm able to calculate the table dependencies using the SQL tables which define the objects found in the AOT ?

Thanks for any help offered.

Tim

p.s. Relationships will also exist within the extended data types used within the table, so I'll also need to consider there at a later date in time. Right now I simply want to get the basics down.

Comment: I think to do this you will also need the metadata of the tables, which can be found in field `Properties` of table `ModelElement`. Unfortunately the values of this field are not human readable, I guess you would have to reengineer their parsing. What's your reason to not do this in AX itself? The reflection options (especially `DictRelation`) found there should make this much easier.

Comment: Also take a look on the `xRefTableRelation` table, which contains the relations as well, if Cross Reference is computed. It is more easily digested. It cannot tell which fields are involved though. It does take care of extended data types.

Comment: Correction to @FH-Inway post - `ModelElementData`